# Deleteing doesn't work from database

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a "file" table in my database that I can send file and retrieve all information that I need. I added a delete button but I don't know why it doesn't work. There are no errors in my console. Can someone please have a look at my code?

php for deleteing:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

include_once 'file.php';

mysqli_query($connect, "SET character_set_client = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect, "SET character_set_connection = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect, "SET character_set_results = utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//$customer = new Customer();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$x = $data->reffer_customer_id;

$reffer_customer_id = $data->reffer_customer_id;
$del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE reffer_customer_id = " . $reffer_customer_id;
//echo $del;
mysqli_query($connect, $del);
$newURL = "/hamatkin/#/allPriceOffers";

header('Location: '.$newURL);

?>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.delete = function(deletingId, $index) {

    $http.post('api/customers-tab/delete-priceOffer.php', { "reffer_customer_id" : deletingId })
        .success(function(data) {

            var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.files = arr;
            var arr2 = arr.split(",");
            arr2.splice($index, 1);
            $route.reload();
        });
    };
```

Html delete button:

```
<td><a ng-click="delete(x.reffer_customer_id, $index)" class="btn btn-primary btn-active">מחיקה</td>
```

Comment: does the generated HTML actually have a value for `$index`?

Comment: run your generated raw sql query direct to phpmyadmin

Comment: @RST yes in the sources I can see that the $index get the value but the "deletingId" doesn't

Comment: @BibekJana this query?   DELETE FROM file WHERE reffer_customer_id=".$reffer_customer_id

Comment: $del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE reffer_customer_id=".$reffer_customer_id;
echo $del; copy the $del value and run to phpmyadmin. @tanyaa

Comment: What is the value of `deletingId` when calling `delete()` function ? Maybe `x` isn't in the scope ? (PS : you'll need to fix your query : potential sql injection)

Comment: @BibekJana I didn't understand exactly what to do

Comment: @micster it should get the value "refer_customer_id"

Comment: Add a slash to your URL to obtain : `/api/customers-tab` instead of `api/customers-tab`. What do you see in your chrome/firefox network console when the request is fired ?

Comment: @Zakaria POST http://localhost:8081/api/customers-tab/delete-priceOffer.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: try your code without the angular code and use hardcoded values. If it works, then it's your js that is failing. check for errors on php and mysql side of things, and your console. Links http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply that to your code.

Comment: @Zakaria what should I know with this error?

Comment: @tanyaa As stated by Fred, yous should first test your PHP code. The 404 error says that the resource doesn't exist. You should get 404 by copying/pasting that URL in your browser. Make sure that the path is correct and then go back to Angluar to test it with the $http service.

Comment: which OS are you on, \*NIX / MAC or Windows? If "not" on Windows, then `delete-priceOffer.php` and `delete-priceoffer.php` are not the same, they are case-sensitive. Make sure that the path (folder/filename) are indeed correct. A 404 is a non-existant file and/or folder error. Also make sure those hyphens aren't supposed to be underscores.

Comment: I copied the path and it goes to my html page where all of my information. no errors

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using windows

Comment: uncomment this: //echo $del; and see what the query is and run it as the same user against your database directly. Some database settings won't let you delete a record without using the primary key (MySQL "safe mode") so you would need something more like this: "DELETE FROM file WHERE file_id=".$your_file_id;.  Some database users won't have "DELETE" permissions at all. If you can't alter the database permissions you may be able to use a soft delete instead of a hard "DELETE" to get your results but that is a larger change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should fix your HTML:

1. I don't know what you mean putting delete function on `ng-click` attribute, probably you want to use `on-click` instead? Correct me if I'm wrong
2. You have opened `<a>` tag, but `</a>` is absent

Corrected HTML button in `<td>` is:

```
<td><a on-click="delete(x.reffer_customer_id, $index); return false;" class="btn btn-primary btn-active">מחיקה</a></td>
```

In the second I propose to check your MySQL scheme of table `file` and be sure that you provide same type of `refferal_customer_id`.
For example, I've wondered that this should be numeric value, than:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    /*
     * I propose to check all data before you will open connection to MySQL,
     * because if data is not correct - connection will not be used
     * I strongly propose to process errors in your client scripts
     */
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    if (!isset($data) ||
        !isset($data->reffer_customer_id) ||
        !is_numeric($data->reffer_customer_id)
    ) {
        echo 'Incorrect data specified';
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * Connecting
     */        
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

    /*
     * I don't know why you using it for delete query if your id is numeric
     */
    mysqli_query($connect, "SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysqli_query($connect, "SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysqli_query($connect, "SET character_set_results = utf8");

    /*
     * I don't recommend you to pass mysql connection error in raw format,
     * because it can be used against you
     * And don't forget to halt your script if error occurred
     */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * Here your delete query
     */
    $delId = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->reffer_customer_id);
    if (!$delId) {
        echo 'Incorrect id for delete query specified';
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * Don't forget to check errors
     */
    if (!mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM file WHERE reffer_customer_id = $delId")) {
        echo "Failed to delete reffer_customer with id: $delId";
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * And close the connection
     */
    mysqli_close($connect);

    /*
     * As for me: better to put next route into response for redirecting from client
     * but I don't know what you will do with this, so, putting header
     */
    header('Location: /hamatkin/#/allPriceOffers');
```

Answer (score -2):

I think your query should be like these:

```
$del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE reffer_customer_id=".$reffer_customer_id." ";
```

Comment: First of all you should not use variables from "non-secure-outside" without escaping. It's a potential way to be hacked via SQL injection. Imagine what your SQL will do if someone pass `" OR 1 = 1;` etc. And second - symbol of double quotes in PHP provides processing variables inside, you should not concatenating them.

Comment: thanks for the advice, im just a novice in php. thank you for sharing your knowledge